# Get the missed call notification

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, calllog

I am developing a application which will determine the phone state such as idle , ringing, off_hook. I am able to differentiate when the user ends the call. If the user doesn't end the call on his own, then obviously it is a missed call. I want to get the notification whenever there is a missed call . I knew that how to get the call logs , but all i want is to get the notification whenever there is a missed call arrives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this using my own logic, by using the boolean variables.

Comment: you could have checked for the last call made/recieved for the MISSED_TYPE of call in call log when you get back to idle state of phone from ringing state of the same!

Comment: Yes, I know I can get the MISSED_TYPE. But I am creating an example which looks to be simple. Whenever we are returning to the IDLE state, I am checking whether the call is OFF_HOOk, if the call is not OFF_HOOK , then I am considering as a missed call

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep memory of the last state.
If you go from idle to ringing and then back to idle, the call is missed.

If you have an "off hook" event in between, the call was taken.